# How to share variables between methods in a class?

Tags: python, oop, methods

I'm looking for a way to make a variable set by one method/function in a class accessible by another method/function in that same class without having to do excess (and problematic code) outside.

Here is an example that doesn't work, but may show you what I'm trying to do :

```
#I just coppied this one to have an init method
class TestClass(object):

    def current(self, test):
        """Just a method to get a value"""
        print(test)
        pass

    def next_one(self):
        """Trying to get a value from the 'current' method"""
        new_val = self.current_player.test
        print(new_val)
        pass
```

Comment: In the same class, or in the same object?

Comment: @mkrieger1: shouldn't the other be marked as a duplicate of this one? This question predates the other, neither has an accepted answer, neither is of superlative quality, and neither has an answer with info that is lacking in the answers of the other question.

Comment: @outis I found the other question clearer.

Answer (score 13):

You set it in one method and then look it up in another:

```
class TestClass(object):

    def current(self, test):
        """Just a method to get a value"""
        self.test = test
        print(test)

    def next_one(self):
        """Trying to get a value from the 'current' method"""
        new_val = self.test
        print(new_val)
```

As a note, you will want to set `self.test` before you try to retrieve it. Otherwise, it will cause an error. I generally do that in `__init__`:

```
class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.test = None

    def current(self, test):
        """Just a method to get a value"""
        self.test = test
        print(test)

    def next_one(self):
        """Trying to get a value from the 'current' method"""
        new_val = self.test
        print(new_val)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
#I just coppied this one to have an init method
class TestClass(object):

    def current(self, test):
        """Just a method to get a value"""
        print(test)
        self.value = test
        pass

    def next_one(self):
        """Trying to get a value from the 'current' method"""
        new_val = self.value
        print(new_val)
        pass

a = TestClass()
b = TestClass()
a.current(10)
b.current(5)
a.next_one()
b.next_one()
```