# Passing variables between methods in Python?

Tags: python

I have a class and two methods. One method gets input from the user and stores it in two variables, `x` and `y`. I want another method that accepts an input so adds that input to `x` and `y`. Like so:

```
class simpleclass(object):
    def getinput(self):
        x = input("input value for x: ")
        y = input("input value for y: ")
    def calculate(self, z):
        print(x + y + z)
```

When I run `calculate(z)` for some number `z`, it gives me errors saying the global variables `x` and `y` aren't defined.

How can `calculate` get access to the `x` and `y` values that were assigned in `getinput`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share variables between methods in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670415/how-to-share-variables-between-methods-in-a-class)

Comment: @outis it's close, but I decided this is the better version of the question to use as a canonical.

Answer (score 17):

These need to be instance variables:

```
class simpleclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def getinput(self):
        self.x = input("input value for x: ")
        self.y = input("input value for y: ")
   
    def calculate(self, z):
        print(self.x + self.y + z)
```

Comment: +1 for most correct answer illustrating use of the __init__() method.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `self.x` and `self.y`. Like so:

```
class simpleclass(object):
    def getinput(self):
        self.x = input("input value for x: ")
        self.y = input("input value for y: ")
    def calculate(self, z):
        print(self.x + self.y + z)
```

Answer (score 3):

`x` and `y` are local variables. They get destroyed when you move out from the scope of that function.

```
class simpleclass(object):
    def getinput(self):
        self.x = input("input value for x: ")
        self.y = input("input value for y: ")
    def calculate(self, z):
        print(int(self.x) + int(self.y) + z)
```

Comment: Probably want to get a number from the string at some point if you're switching to raw_input.

Answer (score 2):

Inside classes, there's a variable called `self` you can use:

```
class Example(object):
    def getinput(self):
        self.x = input("input value for x: ")
    def calculate(self, z):
        print(self.x + z)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def helper(self, jsonInputFile):
        values = jsonInputFile['values']
        ip = values['ip']
        username = values['user']
        password = values['password']
        return values, ip, username, password
    
    def checkHostname(self, jsonInputFile):
       values, ip, username, password = self.helper(jsonInputFile)
       print(values)
       print('---------')
       print(ip)
       print(username)
       print(password)
```

The `__init__` method initializes the class.
The `helper` function just holds some variables/data/attributes and releases them to other methods when you call it. Here `jsonInputFile` is some JSON.
The `checkHostname` method logs in to some device/server to check the hostname; but it needs ip, username and password for that, which it gets by calling the helper method.