# How to pass the lists from one function to multiple functions in a class?

Tags: python

I am trying to pass two lists to other functions. in one function it is executing as I am calling the total function using self. But I shouldn't call the same function in another method too, as the git clone will happen twice. Hence I need to pass the function return values to other function. Is there any way to do this? This total code I am writing in single class.

```
def open_close_lists(self):
    cmd = self.git_clone
    subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
    open_list = os.listdir('open')
    close_list = os.listdir('close')
    return open_list, close_list
```

I have another two functions

```
def fun1(self):
    here I need to use those two lists
def fun2(self):
    here I need to use those two lists
```

Comment: What does your class represent? Does it not make sense to add the two lists as instance attributes (`self.open_list` and `self.close_list`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing variables between methods in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520075/passing-variables-between-methods-in-python)

Comment: Hi, I tried this its giving attribute error as follows:
 rel_two = self.matchRel2(self.open_list, self.close_list)
AttributeError: 'TestMatch' object has no attribute 'open_list'

Answer (score 3):

Here we create a class `OpenCloseLists`, and bind those lists to current instance.

Lists are now available using the `self` keyword.

NOTE: It's common to name classes in CamelCase and variable names with underscores.

```
import os

class OpenCloseLists:
    def __init__(self):
        cmd = self.git_clone
        subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
        self.open_list = os.listdir('open')
        self.close_list = os.listdir('close')
      
    def fun1(self):
        # self.open_list
        # self.close_list
    
    
    def fun2(self):
        # self.open_list
        # self.close_list
```

Comment: Hi Aviv, Its worked. Thanks a lot for the expeditious support :)

Comment: @SinghB Welcome! Keep learning and success! Please mark as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Use global variables.
At the start of your function put

```py
global self.mylist
```

Comment: I will try this also . Thanks for your support MM

Comment: You could also use global variables outside of a class and get rid of the' self.'.